# Configure Sublime Text 3 GIT Path

Tags: json, git, github, sublimetext2, sublimetext3

I keep getting an "Executable '['git']' was not found in PATH. Current PATH" error message when trying GIT STATUS in Sublime Text 3. I have the SublimeGit plugin installed.

I have the following in my Package Settings > Settings - User

```
"git_executables": {
    "git": ["/usr/local/bin/git"],
    "git_flow": ["/usr/local/bin/git", "flow"],
    "legit": ["legit"]
}
```

I have read https://docs.sublimegit.net/quickstart.html, but it does not go through windows paths.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That error message can happen because of operations on a missing or moved file:
See [issue 212](https://github.com/kemayo/sublime-git/issues/212) (for ST2, but possibly relevant for ST3).

> Ok, I think why this bug happened.
>   There was a file that was moved to another location form outside ST2, and Git plugin failed to do something to the file because it no longer existed, but that situation was interpreted as missing git command.

Another workaround mentions:

> Installing python via `homebrew` and restarting ST2 fixed this problem for me:

```
brew install python
```

Also, by [David Gee -- davidagee](https://github.com/davidagee) :

> On OS X Mountain Lion, the only way I was able to fix this, after trying everything in this thread, and additional mucking around with path settings, was to open "`/Users/[me]/Library/Application Support/Sublime Text 2/Packages/Git/Git.sublime-settings`" and to change git_command to "`/usr/local/git/bin/git`".
>   **Adding a `git_command` setting to user prefs doesn't work**.
>
> The plugin seems to ignore the value when set in `Preferences.sublime-settings`.